# IE not firing $.post() / .html() calls correctly

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of jquery code that isn't firing correctly in IE (8 or 9 - although in 9, if I drop out of compatibility mode it works fine)  It works fine in Firefox, chrome, opera & safari...

```
$('.add-event').live('click', function(){
    $('#list').slideUp(1000);
    var date = ($(this).attr('alt'));
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.post("inc/calmod.php", {'sender': 'sent', 'date': date}, function(data){
            $('#change').css({'display': 'none'}).html(data).slideDown(1000);
        }); 
    }, 400);
});
```

In the html, `#list` is a section within the div `#change`:

```
<section class="grid_4" id="change">
    <div class="block-border" id="list">
         {...}
    </div
</section>
```

the ajax call runs through various db calls and eventually outputs a bit of html to go in the div. At the moment in IE, the `slideUp` call runs, but then nothing comes back in it's place.

I have added alerts to test that the `data` variable is outputting - the correct info is passing through the `$.post()` call.

I have replaced the `.html(data)` with a text string (`.data('test')`) - the test string appears where I would expect it to.

It seems like the `data` isn't making it into the `$('#change').html(data)`. I've tried breaking this line into two separate commands and still no joy.

Any suggestions for what to try next?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it do the same thing if you remove the display:none?

Comment: *"I have added alerts to test that the data variable is outputting..."* Why? Both IE8 and IE9 have built-in debugging tools. You can walk through the code, line-by-line, and see exactly what's going on where. All major, modern browsers have these tools built-in except Firefox, which has the excellent Firebug plug-in available for it. `alert` debugging is unnecessary, to put it mildly.

Comment: ...because in IE it wasn't giving me any errors and the quickest and easiest way I could think to test was with this method. I'm always open to learning new methods for optimising my coding, so please share a link or other info on how to better do this.

Comment: @seth: yes. I've removed the slideup, slidedown and css display commands so that it should just swap out the content and no joy. It's still not displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `$.ajax()` instead of `$.post()`?  I've never had any problems with it on IE.

Comment: `post` is just a wrapper for `ajax`, shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: by changing it to `$.ajax()` it's now spitting out info - i've just got to figure out why it's giving me a mysql error now... one step forward though! thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) That function always works better for me than $.get() and $.post().

Comment: huh... i've just added the `type: 'POST'` to the .ajax call to fix the mysql errors and I'm back to not getting the data through! I'm more confused than ever now....

Comment: Are you accepting the data back as HTML or JSON? If JSON, are you using json_encode() or sending the php header as application/json ?

Comment: HTML. `inc/calmod.php` does some simple db queries and outputs the html code for a form

Comment: This has pretty much fixed it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Strange. I suspect one of the 2 following things is happening:

1) You're `.slideUp()` hasn't finished when you try to hide your div

or

2) the `display:none` isn't working.

This would fix both problems, please try:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.post("inc/calmod.php", {'sender': 'sent', 'date': date}, function(data){
        $('#change').hide().html(data).slideDown(1000); //Use .hide()
    }); 
}, 1000); //The delay should be at least equal to the slideUp time
```

Hope this fixes your problem. Cheers